# Aggregate wall time of code blocks in C++

Tags: c++, profiling, timing, boost-timer

I have a large codebase and I want to manually add some timers to profile some sections of the code.
Some of those sections are within a loop, so I would like to aggregate all the wall time spent there for each iteration.

What I'd like to do in a Pythonic pseudo-code:

```
time_step_1 = 0
time_step_2 = 0
for pair in pairs:

    start_step_1 = time.now()
    run_step_1(pair)
    time_step_1 += start_step_1 - time.now()

    start_step_2 = time.now()
    run_step_2(pair)
    time_step_2 += start_step_2 - time.now()

print("Time spent in step 1", time_step_1)
print("Time spent in step 2", time_step_2)
```

Is there a library in C++ to do this?
Otherwise would you recommend using `boost::timer`, create a map of timers and then resume and stop at each iteration?

Comment: You may want to take a look at `std::chrono` library http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono

Comment: Depending on just how much code you want to measure, I would consider using a couple of RAII Classes, one to keep the overall time records and print the summary at the end, and the other to record the individual time for a step, where it's constructor records time.now() and it's destructor some the calculation and adds the duration to the overall tally. With such a system you can have minimal extra code to do the measuring and printing as well as allowing you to calculate average times for steps, how many times they run etc.

Comment: Look into the `ctime` and `chrono` libraries.

Comment: thanks, isn't this a common situation? isn't there already a full fledged library that can handle this without writing my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very advanced, but for basic time measurement, you can use `std::chrono` library, specifically the [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) - the clock
with smallest tick period (= highest accuracy) provided by the implementation.

For some more trivial time measurement, I have used RAII classes similar to this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TimeMeasureGuard {
public:
    using clock_type = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

private:
    const std::string m_testName;
    std::ostream& m_os;

    clock_type::time_point started_at;
    clock_type::time_point ended_at;

public:
    TimeMeasureGuard(const std::string& testName, std::ostream& os = std::cerr)
        : m_testName(testName), m_os(os)
    {
        started_at = clock_type::now();
    }

    ~TimeMeasureGuard()
    {
        ended_at = clock_type::now();

        // Get duration
        const auto duration = ended_at - started_at;

        // Get duration in nanoseconds
        const auto durationNs = std::chrono::nanoseconds(duration).count();
        // ...or in microseconds:
        const auto durationUs
            = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(duration).count();

        // Report total run time into 'm_os' stream
        m_os << "[Test " << std::quoted(m_testName) << "]: Total run time: "
             << durationNs << " ns, " << "or: " << durationUs << " us" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Of course this is a very simple class, which would deserve several improvements before being used for a real measurement.

You can use this class like:

```
std::uint64_t computeSquares()
{
    std::uint64_t interestingNumbers = 0;
    {
        auto time_measurement = TimeMeasureGuard("Test1");

        for (std::uint64_t x = 0; x < 1'000; ++x) {
            for (std::uint64_t y = 0; y < 1'000; ++y) {
                if ((x * y) % 42 == 0)
                    ++interestingNumbers;
            }
        }
    }
    return interestingNumbers;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Computing all x * y, where 'x' and 'y' are from 1 to 1'000..."
              << std::endl;
    const auto res = computeSquares();
    std::cerr << "Interesting numbers found: " << res << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Computing all x * y, where 'x' and 'y' are from 1 to 1'000...
[Test "Test1"]: Total run time: 6311371 ns, or: 6311 us
Interesting numbers found: 111170
```

For simple time measurement cases, this might be easier than using
a whole timer library, and it's just a few lines of code, you don't
need to include lots of headers.

Comment: thanks! this is very useful, what if the guard is **inside** a loop, would it add up each run? also, let's say I want a whole timer library, which one do you recommend?

Comment: @AndreaZonca If the RAII guard is **inside** a loop, it gets created and destroyed each loop iteration. So the result is "a lots of measurements of single loop iteration".
To answer your question about the timer library, I unfortunately cannot tell as I only used `std::chrono`. But I would not hesitate to try `boost::timer`, as Boost libraries are usually very high quality.